# Why does Okta-React Login redirect to blank page when using Django?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, django, okta

I am using Okta-React for authentication in my React project and when I run the React test server my login authenticates successfully and redirects to the account page. When I run the React build command and render the build files with Django, my login authenticates properly, but when it redirects back to my site I get a blank /implicit/callback page, no login token or user info, and the code & state gets stuck in the URL. Does anyone know why this is only happening when using Django, and what I can do to resolve this issue?

Here is my authConfig:

```
const config = {
  issuer: 'https://dev-#######.okta.com/oauth2/default',
  redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/implicit/callback',
  clientId: '#@#@#@#@#@#@#@#@#',
  pkce: true
};

export default config;
```

Here is my accountAuth

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useOktaAuth } from '@okta/okta-react';
import '../scss/sass.scss';
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
import 'react-bootstrap';

const AccountAuth = () => {
  const { authState, authService } = useOktaAuth();
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!authState.isAuthenticated) {
      // When user isn't authenticated, forget any user info
      setUserInfo(null);
    } else {
      authService.getUser().then((info) => {
        setUserInfo(info);
      });
    }
  }, [authState, authService]); // Update if authState changes

  localStorage.setItem("username", userInfo && userInfo.given_name)

  const login = async () => {
    // Redirect to '/account_page' after login
    localStorage.setItem("accountLink", "/account_page")
    localStorage.setItem("loginPostingVisibilityStyle", { display: "none" })
    localStorage.setItem("postingVisibleStyle", { display: 'block' })
    authService.login('/auth_index');
  }

  const logout = async () => {
    // Redirect to '/' after logout
    localStorage.setItem("username", null)
    localStorage.setItem("accountLink", "/auth_index")
    localStorage.setItem("loginPostingVisibilityStyle", { display: "block" })
    localStorage.setItem("postingVisibleStyle", { display: 'none' })
    authService.logout('/');
  }

  return authState.isAuthenticated ?
    <button className="settings-index" onClick={logout}>Logout</button> :
    <button className="settings-index" onClick={login}>Login</button>;


};

export default AccountAuth;
```

Here is an example of the URL when it's stuck

```
http://localhost:8000/implicit/callback?code=-mRoU2jTR5HAFJeNVo_PVZsIj8qXuB1-aioFUiZBlWo&state=c9RXCvEgQ4okNgp7C7wPkI62ifzTakC0Ezwd8ffTEb29g5fNALj7aQ63fjFNGGhT
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Django wants to handle the callback, but I'd rather have the LoginCallback handle it. Have you found a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're [handling the callback](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/sign-into-spa/react/handle-callback/) to exchange the authorization_code for tokens. You might want to check out Okta's [React sample app](https://github.com/okta/samples-js-react) to see how it works.